# Duplicating page in MS Word without Copy and Paste

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

Does MS Word 2013 display an easy way to duplicate an entire page without using Copy and Paste or programming with Visual Basic?

Comment: Does Word 2013, have the ability to copy the contents of a page, in a documnet with multiple pages? It does not.  You can indeed programmatical copy the contents on a page in a Word document

Comment: I suppose you can insert the contents of another document, and you could in theory, insert a word document page if the document only contained a single page.